# First paragraph different size inside various divs

Tags: css

How can I give the first p.h2 a different font-size using css than the following ones:

```
    <div class="page-blocks">
<div class="index-section">
    <div class="grid">
        <p class="h2">lorem ipsum dorem</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="index-section">
    <div class="grid">
        <p class="h2">lorem ipsum dorem</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="index-section">
    <div class="grid">
        <p class="h2">lorem ipsum dorem</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried the following:

```
.page-blocks p.h2   {
    font-size:2.5em;
}
.page-blocks p.h2:nth-child(1)  {
    font-size:3em;
}
```

but that sets all p.h2 to 3em

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the first child of the `.page-blocks` wrapper. Then drill down

```css
.page-blocks .index-section:first-child .h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-blocks">
  <div class="index-section">
    <div class="grid">
      <p class="h2">lorem ipsum dorem</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="index-section">
    <div class="grid">
      <p class="h2">lorem ipsum dorem</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="index-section">
    <div class="grid">
      <p class="h2">lorem ipsum dorem</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes that seems to work however in my code it doesn't maybe because it has another div before? I just edited my initial html

Comment: Please don't edit question that invalidate answers based on your original HTML. If you don't provide accurate information at the start it's of little value.

Comment: I've rolled the edit back. If you want to ask a NEW question based on the new HTML please do so but you can just use `.page-blocks .index-section:nth-child(2) .h2`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the p:nth-child(1) selector in CSS to specifically define style for that paragraph tag

Comment: Nope that will select all the paragraphs as they are all first children

Comment: that's not true may you read question careful

Comment: I think I am not wording my answer correctly. I didn't said copy and paste p:nt-child[1] in CSS. I was trying to explain how it can be done. It will still depend on OP to find out his pattern and use it.